# C++ MFC Get current date and time

Tags: c++, date, mfc, time

I've been programming in VB.NET for most of my very programming career.  I have a C++ project provided to me, which I need to make a few modifications, and I am feeling hopelessly lost and confused.

It is a Visual Studio 2008 MFC project in C++.

an output variable has been defined:

```
char szout[900];
```

---

This line below, is used to append values to the output variable before output:

```
strcpy(szout, "TextHere")
```

---

So one of the many examples from searching, that i have tried, was to include at the top:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

---

And then for my code:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
char myDate[20] = st;
CT2CA outputDate(myDate);
strcat(szout, outputDate);
```

---

For some reason the variables appended on to szout must be of type CT2CA, which i'm not really sure what this is either.

But then I get the following errors on the second and third line (char myDate...etc...) and (CT2CA output....etc....)

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'SYSTEMTIME' to 'char [20]'

error C2664: 'ATL::CW2AEX<>::CW2AEX(LPCWSTR) throw(...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [20]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

---

So I'll clarify, I am a complete novice with this, and would appreciate any and all help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using MFC, why not:

```
// uses printf() format specifications for time
CString t = CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%H:%M");

// Or, if you have OLE Support
CString t = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%H:%M");
```

Comment: Project builds without error if i do not include either line.  Including the first option gives this error: error C2664: 'CString ATL::CTime::Format(LPCTSTR) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'LPCTSTR'     ------ including the second option gives this error: error C2664: 'CString ATL::COleDateTime::Format(DWORD,LCID) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'DWORD'

Comment: Also, if instead i put .Format(0, "%H:%M");   , it gets rid of the DWORD conversion error..but then generates a new error for parameter 2, that it cant be converted to LCID.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments =\...  if i remove all parameters from the .Format method, then it compiles okay.  But i would still like to be able to do the formatting as you had shown.

Comment: @Adam `LPCTSTR` translates to mean *"Long Pointer to a Constant STRing of Tchars"*, which means you're in Windows Unicode land.  Changing it to `.Format(L"%H:%M")` might just fix it for you, but I myself have never really understood what best practices are for this sort of thing.  This might shed some light: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide2.aspx

Comment: I'll throw in that Joel Spolsky thinks this is the minimum every programmer should know about Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thank you for answer Chad, and the help Hostile Fork :) *nice name BTW*.  I read the article by Joel Spolsky, very inlightening, thank you.

Comment: CT2CA isn't a type, it's an MFC [string conversion macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/87zae4a3.aspx#atl70stringconversionclassesmacros).

Comment: This will get the time in the local time zone format. How do I get the UTC time?

Comment: @Damian After calling `GetCurrentTime()`, convert it using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx#coledatetime__getassystemtime then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

In MFC the following code is for current date in MMDDYYYY format.

```
CTime t = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
CString s = t.Format("%m%d%Y");
```